# How do I filter a table property in a parameterized query in Lightswitch for cascading selections?

Tags: lightswitch-2013

I have a cascading autocomplete data grid(top grid labeled Trip) in which a customer type is selected in the first autocomplete, which filters the Customers autocomplete, which filters the address Locations.
I don't seem to be able to display the City property from the Locations table provided from the CityByLocationID query.
Here is an example of where I am.
[image]

I have added the queries below the Trip grid to show they are selecting the right table records.
I have referenced these tutorials for research
(https://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry/)

(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/01/12/creating-cascading-drop-down-lists-in-visual-studio-lightswitch.aspx)

but they do not seem to explain binding a property in the same table, from another query. In this case, the City property from the selected Location record.
As you can see at the bottom, the CityOfSelectedLocationID returns the proper Location ID values, but I do not know how to bind the City to a text, label field, or an autocomplete box.
I have the parametrized CityofLocationsId bound to the LocationId of the Trip table which gives me the proper address information(as seen at bottom), but in the same query how do I bind the City to a field? (i.e. City field in the top grid labeled Trip)

[image]

(Edit)
The CityOfLocaitonID as above is set to Id=Id(parameter) bind to Trip.SelectedItem.Location.Id
But if I add City = City (property) and bind to a Locations(Entity) property it still returns the Address value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I feel really silly about this because I knew it would be something easy I was overlooking. I simply added "Other Screen Data" and entered Location.City! Queries were not even necessary.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsQN3.jpg)